# no response from TCP socket in Apache Camel using Netty4

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, apache-camel, netty

this is my route

```
from(Endpoints.login.inRoute())
    .process(new LoginRequestProcessor())
    .to("netty4:tcp://somehost:9001?textline=true")
    .process(new LoginResponseProcessor())
    .to(Endpoints.login.outRoute());
```

I just want to communicate with a socket server running at *somehost* at port 9001 but I'm not getting any response.

However, I tested the socket server using telnet and it is alive and responding.

Also, I writed a simple TCP socket server using C and tested exactly the same Camel route but with the address of my local server (localhost) with its local port and everything works fine.

What could be happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Tried setting sync=true?

Comment: Do you have logs?

Answer (score 0):

Try pass the param synchronous=true, it will force your call be synchronous.